# display an alert if active

Tags: jquery

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnXdv/12/

It works well, but I need to add a little extra too it.

I need to display an alert when an active nav is clicked a second time.

For example, if nav1 is clicked to activate the dropdown, if nav1 is clicked again, it should display an alert,  If some other part of the page is clicked when nav1 is active, it should not display an alert.

Also, if nav1 is active and nav2 is activated, no alert should be displayed.  However, when nav2 is active, and if nav2 is clicked again, it should display an alert.

*Sorry for closing the previous question which was similar to this, it had a fundamental issue with it.*

**EDIT 1:**

All the rest of the original behaviour of the script must remain intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm not sure if this is the "correct" solution but it works, I use the event property originalEvent to know when an event has been fired from the GUI and when from the code:

```
$('.nav1, .nav2').click(function(event) {
    if (typeof event.originalEvent != "undefined") {
        if (this.data_clicked) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('nav1'))
                alert("I'm the happy icon Home!");
            else if($(this).hasClass('nav2'))
                alert("I'm the sad icon Phone");
            $(this).click();
            return(false);
        }
        this.data_clicked = true;
    } else {
        this.data_clicked = false;
    }
    if (typeof event == "undefined")
        alert("HAAA HAAA!");
    $(this).siblings('.nav1.active, .nav2.active').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**EDIT:** Try it, now it close the menu after showing the alert.
**EDIT 2:** Ok now it shows a different message, I don't like very much the hasClass conditionals but I think it's the best in this case.
Here you have the *lastly new* working version, test it and look if have the behavoir that you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/mnXdv/48/

Comment: This solution does look appealing and works almost perfectly.  Only problem is that after displaying the alert, the active dropdown should close.

Comment: @oshirowanen Try the new solution, I've just added a `$(this).click();` after the `alert`.

Comment: Remove the `<pre>` tags you have in your answer - simply indenting by 4 spaces is enough for SO to identify your text as code. For inline-code you can use backticks (`). As for syntax highlighting, SO tries to automatically figure out what language the code snippet is in (when not in pre tags, apparently!).

Comment: You can click on the code sample button to display syntax highlighting.  Hover over the buttons in the text editor to see what they are about.  But it's the button with the curly brackets you're interested in.

Comment: @oshirowanen done, different message for each message, but too late :) @no.good.at.coding thank you, without the `<pre>` tags it works ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (slightly) messy answer. The problem is that you're also programmatically triggering the `click` on the two `navX` elements so a click to close one also causes an event to be received on the other. My solution involves sending a extra piece of data with the `trigger`ed event and modify the handler to behave differently if the event originated programmatically. I'm not aware of any way to differentiate user-initiated and code-triggered events but if there is a way, that would be much cleaner.

Note I've modified your `click()` invocations in two places to `trigger('click', true);`. I've also [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/mnXdv/40/) so you should be able to try this out.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        $('.nav1.active, .nav2.active').trigger('click', true);
        $('.nav1, .nav2').removeClass("active");
    });

    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
        $(this).css('left', $(this).prev().position().left);
    });

    $('.nav1, .nav2').click(function(event, isTrigger) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav1.active, .nav2.active').trigger('click', true);

        if(!isTrigger && $(this).hasClass('active')){
                alert("Is Active");
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.nav1, .nav2').disableSelection();

    $('.item').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggle();
        $('.nav1.active, .nav2.active').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Never mind, this doesn't fulfill the second requirement (clicking the other nav element should *not* trigger the alert) - working on a fix

Comment: I've added an edit 1 to the original question.  Yes, you beat me to it regarding the clicking elsewhere while active.

Comment: @oshirowanen I've updated my answer with a solution that works - I'm not sure if it's the most elegant though.

Comment: This does work, could this be improved by using originalEvent as described by Terseus?

Comment: `originalEvent` is the native browser event object - it's called so because the events that you work with using jQuery are jQuery's own `event` objects that are created from the native, 'original' event. If you notice, Terseus is also adding a property (`data_clicked`) to help differentiate how the event was triggered, essentially the same thing as this code.

Comment: We're both solving the same problem - that of handling a code-triggered event differently from a user triggered one. Either approach should work for you - if you're not ok with changing `click` to `trigger` then Terseus' approach should do just fine. And right now, I'm not certain how to further improve this :)